# Oracle SQL Developer get table rows older than n months

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sysdate

In Oracle SQL Developer, I have a table called t1  who have two columns col1 defined as NUMBER(19,0) and col2 defined as TIMESTAMP(3).
I have these rows

```
col1           col2
1     03/01/22 12:00:00,000000000
2     03/01/22 13:00:00,000000000
3     26/11/21 10:27:11,750000000
4     26/11/21 10:27:59,606000000
5     16/12/21 11:47:04,105000000
6     16/12/21 12:29:27,101000000
```

My sysdate looks like this:

```
select sysdate from dual;

    SYSDATE
    03/03/22
```

I want to create a stored procedure (SP) which will delete rows older than 2 months and displayed message  n rows are deleted

But when i execute this statement

```
select * from t1 where to_date(TRUNC(col2), 'DD/MM/YY') < add_months(sysdate, -2);
```

I don't get the first 2 rows of my t1 table. I get more than 2 rows

```
1     03/01/22 12:00:00,000000000
2     03/01/22 13:00:00,000000000
```

How can i get these rows and deleted it please ?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second). It **ALWAYS** has all of those components and it is **NEVER** stored with a particular formatting (such as `DD/MM/RR`).

Your client application (i.e. SQL Developer) may choose to **DISPLAY** the binary `DATE` value in a human readable manner by formatting it as `DD/MM/RR` but that is a function of the client application you are using and not the database.

When you show the entire value:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS dt FROM DUAL;
```

Then it outputs (depending on time zone):

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 2022-01-03 10:11:28 |

If you compare that to your values then you can see that `2022-01-03 12:00:00` is not "more than 2 months ago" so it will not be matched.

What you appear to want is not "more than 2 months ago" but "equal to or more than 2 months, ignoring the time component, ago"; which you can get using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  col2 < add_months(TRUNC(sysdate), -2) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  TRUNC(col2) <= add_months(TRUNC(sysdate), -2);
```

*(Note: the first query would use an index on `col2` but the second query would not; it would require a function-based index on `TRUNC(col2)` instead.)*

---

Also, don't use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type. `TO_DATE` takes a string as the first argument and not a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` so Oracle will perform an implicit conversion using `TO_CHAR` and if the format models do not match then you will introduce errors (and since any user can set their own date format in their session parameters at any time then you may get errors for one user that are not present for other users and is very hard to debug).
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=074afebdd995d30e734dce53f8bb82c7)*

Comment: Hi @MT0, How can i put it stored procedure to delete all rows equal to or more than 2 months

Comment: @ln3106 `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE col2 < add_months(TRUNC(sysdate), -2) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;` and then wrap it in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just:

```
select * 
from t1 
where col2 < add_months(sysdate, -2);
```

Comment: Hi @David Aldridge , it doesn't work, i get more than two rows

Comment: There are four rows in the data that are older than two months

Comment: Hi @David Aldridge, how can i put it in a stored procedure, can you explain me please